# Installing librdkafka on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to build two different applications that both depend on librdkafka. The applications are written in .NET Core and Go.

I have installed the confluent platform using apt, and installed it from the confluent repository. I assume that installing this platform includes librdkafka (and makes it available for .NET and> GO packages).

When i try to build either, i receive two different errors.

For the Go app:

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- rdkafka
Package rdkafka was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `rdkafka.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'rdkafka' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

For the .NET Core app:

```
System.DllNotFoundException : Failed to load the librdkafka native library.
    Stack Trace:
       at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.Librdkafka.Initialize(String userSpecifiedPath)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Producer`2..ctor(ProducerBuilder`2 builder)
   at Confluent.Kafka.ProducerBuilder`2.Build()
```

Are there any subsequent steps one has to take after installing the confluent platform, to make librdkafka available for applications?

Comment: Why are you trying to build it?

Comment: I'm not trying to build librdkafka itself. I'm trying to build projects in go and net core respectively. The projects each have packages that depend on librdkafka.

Comment: 1) `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` 2) I've not needed to use the apt repos for either language, but I also don't think it sets up the build path to include the linkers for golang or .NET

Comment: The env var is empty

Comment: `Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'rdkafka.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable`

Comment: That makes sense. I can't seem to find the dir in question. I assume the dir must be within the dir of the confluent package i installed with apt. However, i can't find it.